# Is there a way to access data coming from BLE device from single file which keeps updating?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to access characteristic values of BLE from one dart file, What I am doing is that I am connecting the device from one activity and then sending the device info to all other activities. But to get values I have to write the same code again and again to all activities/dart files.
For example i am connecting device in an activity like this:

```
StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data
                      .map(
                        (r) => ScanResultTile(
                      result: r,
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        r.device.connect();
                        print('DEVICE CONNECTED');
                        return BluetoothConnectedSuccess(device: r.device);
```

Here `device: r.device` is the device that i have connected to my Flutter App. Now if i want to display device data i have to initilaze these lines of code everytime i jump to any screen/activity:

```
class BluetoothConnectedSuccess extends StatefulWidget {
  const BluetoothConnectedSuccess({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);
  final BluetoothDevice device;
  @override
  _BluetoothConnectedSuccessState createState() =>
      _BluetoothConnectedSuccessState();
}

class _BluetoothConnectedSuccessState extends State<BluetoothConnectedSuccess> {
    // BLE
      final String SERVICE_UUID = "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b";
      final String CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8";
      bool isReady;
      Stream<List<int>> stream;
      List<int> lastValue;
      List<double> traceDust = List();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        isReady = false;
        connectToDevice();
      }
    
      connectToDevice() async {
        await widget.device.connect();
        discoverServices();
      }
    
      discoverServices() async {
        List<BluetoothService> services = await widget.device.discoverServices();
        services.forEach((service) {
          if (service.uuid.toString() == SERVICE_UUID) {
            service.characteristics.forEach((characteristic) {
              if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
                characteristic.setNotifyValue(!characteristic.isNotifying);
                stream = characteristic.value;
                print(stream);
                lastValue = characteristic.lastValue;
                print(lastValue);
    
                setState(() {
                  isReady = true;
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    
      _dataParser(List<int> data) {
        var value = Uint8List.fromList(data);
        print("stream.value: $value"); // stream.value: [33]
        var hr = ByteData.sublistView(value, 0, 1);
        print("Heart rate: ${hr.getUint8(0)}");
        return hr.getUint8(0); // Heart rate: 33
      }
```

It's creating a lot of mess to write the same code again and again to the activities where BLE data is needed.
Is there a way to only call this connected device from a single file instead of initializing the same code in every activity?

This is the link to my [repo](https://github.com/nabiasalman99/Epicare-Medical-App) for a look at what I am doing on every activity/screen with BLE device data.
Please help me out as I am new to Flutter. Thank you

Comment: Use get package it will bring your code into half,  easy management of widgets and actually i implemented this yesterday so if you want i will make you know how i used ble with get.

Comment: could you plz tell me how do i make it, as i am new to flutter and i have no idea about it? 
Many Thanks

Comment: I can't share github repo link due to privacy concern , i am sharing part of it to make u understand.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly learn basic of  state management  using Get you can refer to my code here what happens is every time something changes or upadtes it  will immediate show in UI using specific Get Widgets like Obx and GetX , these widgets listen to changes in value which are marked with obs (observable).
for exmaple :

```
Obx(
     () => ble.isScan.value ? LinearProgressIndicator() : SizedBox(),
        ),
```

this  will observe the changes in isScan value .

```
class BleServices extends GetxController {
  FlutterBlue blue = FlutterBlue.instance;
  BluetoothDevice d;
  var connectedDevices = List<BluetoothDevice>().obs;
  var scanResults = List<ScanResult>().obs;
  var bleState = BluetoothState.off.obs;
  var isScan = false.obs;
  var scanRequire = false.obs;
  var bluetoothServices = List<BluetoothService>().obs;
  var discoveringServices = false.obs;
  var characteristics = List<BluetoothCharacteristic>().obs;

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    final perb = await Permission.bluetooth.status.isGranted;
    final perL = await Permission.location.status.isGranted;
    if (perb && perL) {
      getConnectedDevices();
    } else {
      await Permission.bluetooth.request();
      await Permission.location.request();
    }
    isScanning();
    state();
  }

  isDiscovering() async {}
  getConnectedDevices() async {
    final connectedDevice = await blue.connectedDevices;
    connectedDevices.value = connectedDevice;
    AppLogger.print('connected devices : $connectedDevice');
    if (connectedDevice.length == 0) {
      scanRequire.value = true;
      searchDevices();
    }
    return connectedDevice;
  }

  searchDevices() {
    // AppLogger.print('pppppppppppppp');

    blue
        .scan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 20))
        .distinct()
        .asBroadcastStream()
        .listen((event) {
      AppLogger.print(event.toString());
      scanResults.addIf(!scanResults.contains(event), event);
    });
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 20), () {
      blue.stopScan();
      Get.showSnackbar(GetBar(
        message: 'scan is finished',
      ));
    });
  }

  isScanning() {
    blue.isScanning.listen((event) {
      AppLogger.print(event.toString());
      isScan.value = event;
    });
  }

  state() {
    blue.state.listen((event) {
      AppLogger.print(event.toString());
      bleState.value = event;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: error: The getter 'bluetooth' isn't defined for the type 'Permission'. (undefined_getter at [epicare] lib\Bluetooth.dart:20) , i am getting this error on line: "    final perb = await Permission.bluetooth.status.isGranted;
"

Comment: Also i have made a new dart file for this class you have asked, there is no need for me to send r. device now to jump to the page where BLE is needed? i just have to call this class and use OBx where BLe data is needed right?

Comment: Did you installed  Permission plugin?

Comment: is the the one for permission? import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Comment: Also there is an error on Undefined name 'AppLogger'.

Comment: Could you please provide a solution to the code for BLE that I have provided in my question, the code you are using is very different from mine. I am using UUIDs in it as well.

Comment: I should have done editing before pasting here .  Delete app logger  line it just custom class I made for debugging  and  permession handler indeed necessary for ble to work   properly .   Currently I have implemented  general case to read data from any UUID not specific , you can do editing   and pass UUID for specification

Comment: I am using Obx in another activity but for the line , i am getting error at word ble

Comment: See some tutorial on get there you will know how dependency are getting  initialized and used you will not able to achieve it using my code i just show you way of doing it . And ble here is intialize by me in class where i am use bleServices like var ble = G.put(BleServices()).

Comment: First you should learn Get state management then you will easily understand otherwise using just my code you cannot achieve i showed you how you can achieve easy management of ble.